# Selecting all movies where specified actors worked together

Tags: sql, mysql

Here's a query I wrote trying to find all movies that three actors have been in together:

```
select distinct
    Movie
from 
    CastMember
where 
    Movie in (
        select Movie
        from CastMember
        where Actor = 1
    )
    and Movie in (
        select Movie
        from CastMember
        where Actor = 2
    ) 
    and Movie in (
        select Movie
        from CastMember
        where Actor = 3
    )
```

Movie and Actor are FKs to a Movie and Actor table. CastMember just has two columns: Movie and Actor.

Is there a better way to write this?

Update: thinking of just using `INTERSECT`

```
select Movie
from CastMember
where Actor = 1
intersect
select Movie
from CastMember
where Actor = 2
intersect
select Movie
from CastMember
where Actor = 3
```

Comment: On your update, `intersect` can work fine but it's a very expensive operation if you have to do it for more than just a few queries, as it has to run each query individually, then process the result sets another time to find matches between the sets.

Comment: Au contraire, depending on the actual data and indexing `intersect` can be the most efficient version as there's no aggregation & `HAVING`. And using a list of values in `WHERE` might forfeit index usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will this do the trick?

```
select m.Title
from Movie m
    inner join CastMember cm on cm.MovieId = m.Id
    inner join Actor a on cm.ActorId = a.Id
where a.Name in ('John Travolta', 'Uma Thurman')
group by m.Title
having count(m.Id) > 1 -- this should be replaced with the number of items in the "in" list minus 1.
```

Comment: ah! clever! you can do `count(m.Id) = 2` here, too. it's probably important to note that there has to be a unique constraint on `CastMember` for this to work, though. If `CastMember` allowed duplicates this wouldn't work (but it does have that constraint, so this is great haha).

Comment: lol, now I'm embarrassed I haven't thought of that haha have an upvote =)

Comment: If `CastMember` allowed duplicates you could use `COUNT(DISTINCT m.Actor)`

Comment: If there were duplicates, I'd assume that means the actor played multiple roles in the same movie - in that case I'd probably want a Character table as well that joins (pun intended) in the fun.

Answer (score 5):

`distinct` is pretty much always a sign that something's wrong.

I'm fighting with myself to try and see why this wouldn't produce exactly the same output:

```
select Movie from CastMember where Actor in (1,2,3) -- group by Movie
```

Seems your schema is confusing: it's hard to tell what's a FK and what's coming from where - that's probably why I'm over-simplifying the query here.

Let's see... I'm not a huge UML fan, so I might have gotten this wrong, but let's say you have this:

[image: yUML showing Movie, CastMember and Actor relationships and columns]

Then you'd want to use `inner join` to "link" the tables - having FK columns named with a `[FKTableName][Id]` scheme makes it much easier to see what's what IMO:

```
select m.Title
from Movie m
    inner join CastMember cm on m.Id = cm.MovieId
    inner join Actor a on a.Id = cm.ActorId
where a.Id in (1,2,3)
group by m.Title
```

---

Now, the above simply returns all movies any of actors 1, 2 and 3 have starred in - and you want the movies where *all* these actors have starred in *together*.

I'd work with the `CastMember` table at first, and select all rows with `ActorId` 1, 2, and 3:

```
select MovieId, ActorId from CastMember where ActorId in (1,2,3)
```

Then, I know I'm expecting 3 rows per movie - assuming SQL Server here, I could use a CTE and a windowing function to partition the results by `MovieId` and filter for movies that have 3 rows:

```
with filter as (
    select MovieId, row_number() over (partition by MovieId order by MovieId, ActorId) RN
    from CastMember
    where ActorId in (1,2,3))
select MovieId from filter where RN = 3
```

Now I know what Id's I'm after - If I make that `select` another CTE, I can now select all rows from `Movie`:

```
with filter as (
    select MovieId, row_number() over (partition by MovieId order by MovieId, ActorId) RN
    from CastMember
    where ActorId in (1,2,3)
)
, movies as (
    select MovieId from filter where RN = 3
)
select m.*
from Movie m
inner join movies on m.Id = movies.MovieId
```

And now I no longer have Kill Bill for Uma Thurman and John Travolta :)

---

Unfortunately [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) doesn't support CTE's and windowing functions (AFAIK). The equivalent would use much less elegant nested subqueries and temp tables; I'll leave it to a [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) reviewer to come up with a cleaner way - anyway I'd still recommend avoiding columns named after tables - a "Movie" column in a "Movie" table that means "Title", and then a "Movie" column in a many-to-many association table where "Movie" means "the primary key of the Movie table", definitely needs to be altered.

Comment: this still doesn't work. If we have Uma Thurman and John Travolta, we get Pulp Fiction (desired), Kill Bill (not desired--John's not in it), and Saturday Night Fever (not desired--Uma's not in it) because it's selecting movies where any of the actors match any of the ids in your in clause

Comment: maybe it's best to use an `INTERSECT` of three queries?

Comment: @JosephNields edited, ...not sure it's the best way though.